# How i can set cookie and json in server response and redirect to client url/ PassportJS NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, passport.js

Me need set cookie with httlp only in server with using passport js ("Google"), after i set cookie me need redirect but i can't i see this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (H:\1HF_solution\location\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (H:\1HF_solution\location\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:915:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (H:\1HF_solution\location\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:953:18)
```

I can only set cookie or redirect but i need both. Help please
Here my code
google-strategy.ts

```
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import { IGoogleDto } from '../interfaces/user-interface';
import userService, { IServerData } from '../service/user-service';

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: '/api/oauth/google/callback',
    },
    async function (
      accessToken: any,
      refreshToken: any,
      profile: { _json: IGoogleDto },
      done: (arg0: any, arg1: boolean | IServerData | { registrationToken: string }, arg2: undefined) => void
    ) {
      try {
        const googleDto: IGoogleDto = profile._json;

        const result = await userService.findOrCreateForGoogle(googleDto);
       'result: {refreshToken:'',userDto:'user data object'}

        done(null, result, null);
      } catch (err) {
        done(err, null, null);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});
```

oauth-router.ts

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import { IRTRequest } from '../interfaces/user-interface';
import { IServerData } from '../service/user-service';
require('../strategy/google-strategy');

const router = Router();

const CLIENT_URL = process.env.CLIENT_URL;

router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  });
  res.clearCookie('refreshToken');
  res.redirect(CLIENT_URL);
});

router.get('/google/success', (req: IRTRequest, res, next) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'successfully',
      user: req.user,
    });

    res.cookie('refreshToken', req.user.refreshToken, {
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
    });
  }
});

router.get('/google/failed', (req, res) => {
  res.status(401).json({
    success: false,
    message: 'failure',
  });
});

router.get(
  '/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: 'success',
    failureRedirect: 'failed',
  })
);

router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email', 'profile'] }));
```

In client i call

```
  const GoogleHandler = () => {
    window.open(process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_OAUTH_URL, '_self');
  };
```

I try use router.get(url,(req,res)=>{

```
router.get('/google/callback', async (req: IRTRequest, res, next) => {
  return await passport.authenticate(
    'google',
    {
      successRedirect: 'login/success',
      failureRedirect: 'failed',
    },
    async (err, data: IServerData) => {
      'set cokkie here and redirect but i have error'
    }
  )(req, res);
});
```

Also i try end() but i stay in server url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.S. I sovled this problem. For avoid this situation i use cookie, and set my userData and set maxAge 5 minutes, this is not secret info and after this 5 minutes thei will cleared and no one get read this data, but if someone can it is not a problem. In client i just read my cookie and set data using redux-tookit